# How can I print the decision tree classifier in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree

export_graphviz(treeclf, out_file='tree_titanic.dot',      feature_names=feature_cols)

## At the command line, run this to convert to PNG:

## dot -Tpng tree_titanic.dot -o tree_titanic.png

I am using the above code, but when I try to run the (dot command) in the terminal, it doesn't work. How can I run this command in jupyter to visualize the tree? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can run terminal commands in jupyter by putting a `!` before the command.  For example:

```
! dot -Tpng tree_titanic.dot -o tree_titanic.png
```

You'll probably need to have Graphviz installed on your system in order to have the dot program.

You can then use the display sub-module in jupyter/ipython to display the image off the local file system.